# Is it possible to use MediaWiki Math extension for Semantic Media Wiki annotations?

Tags: mediawiki, mathjax, mediawiki-extension

We are building a knowledge base storing a lot of formulas. For presentation purposes, all our formulas are displayed inside a `<math>...</math>` pair of tags.

We recently enabled SMW extension, with the intent to store all the formulas as semantic annotations.
Sadly, we cannot find a way to enter such an annotation within the math tags.

Is there a way to achieve the desired results ?
i.e., storing formulas as SMW annotations, and having them rendered as Latex formula each time they are presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the content of XML-style tags (`<foo>...</foo>`) is interpreted literally, while the content of template-style functions (`{{#foo:...}}`) is interpreted as wikimarkup and property lookups or other semantic syntax will work. There is a special function `#tag` to convert the first type to the second. So you can probably use something like `{{#tag:math|{{#show|SomeFormula|?formula}} }}`.

Comment: Thank you very much, that adresses our need very elegantly !
Just a remark, I do not know if it is a typo in your answer or a difference in our wikis: we had to replace the first `|` in each function invocation by a `:`, resulting in :

`{{#tag:math|{{#show:SomeFormula|?formula}} }}`

Answer (score 0):

To complete **Tgr** answer:

In order for the formula to actually show up, one should make sure that the `formula` property does not have the default `Page`type. Assigning it the `Text`type works very well (perhaps other types would work as well).

To do that, go to the *Properties:Formula* special page on the wiki, and create it with the content:

```
[[Has type::Text]]
```